# Wildcards in VisibleExternalCommands not working in PSSessionConfiguration

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to use wildcards like "c:\scripts\*.ps1" in *VisibleExternalCommands* for *New-PSSessionConfigurationFile* and the resulting .pssc file looks fine, but cannot get it to work as expected and the documentation is weak here. I can only make VisibleExternalCommands work by giving full path.

Steps to reproduce, tested on Win10 with PowerShell 5.1:

Setup directory and scripts:

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
mkdir c:\scripts
echo "Write-Output hello" | Out-File c:\scripts\hello.ps1 -Force
echo "Write-Output world" | Out-File c:\scripts\world.ps1 -Force
```

Using Wildcard (NOT working):

```
New-PSSessionConfigurationFile -VisibleExternalCommands "c:\scripts\*.ps1" -Path c:\scripts\TestWildcard.pssc -SessionType RestrictedRemoteServer -LanguageMode FullLanguage
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name TestWildcard -Path c:\scripts\TestWildcard.pssc -Force
Invoke-Command . -ConfigurationName TestWildcard {c:\scripts\hello.ps1; c:\scripts\world.ps1}
# Fails to recognize both .ps1 scripts as external commands
```

Using Full Path (works fine):

```
New-PSSessionConfigurationFile -VisibleExternalCommands "c:\scripts\hello.ps1" -Path c:\scripts\TestFullPath.pssc -SessionType RestrictedRemoteServer -LanguageMode FullLanguage
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name TestFullPath -Path c:\scripts\TestFullPath.pssc -Force
Invoke-Command . -ConfigurationName TestFullPath {c:\scripts\hello.ps1; c:\scripts\world.ps1}
# Prints hello and fails to recognize c:\scripts\world.ps1
```

The documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssessionconfigurationfile?view=powershell-5.1) says that wildcard characters are supported, but shows no example of it.

**Am I missing something or is this a bug?**

Comment: Discovered another rarity: If using *Enter-PSSession* instead of *Invoke-Command* and saving the logic as a script file and executing that, then it seems to be running in an un-restricted session - not using the PSSessionConfiguration which is the whole point, because it WILL then print both "hello" and "world" in both the wildcard and full path scenarios. Furthermore if executing *Get-Command* within the script file when using Enter-PSSession, in addition to the expected 8 cmdlets (*Exit-PSSession* etc.), it will return all sorts of other cmdlets, which were meant to be restricted away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VisibleExternalCommands` option does not accept wildcards. This documentation bug was fixed in https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/4756.